# How to turn objects in an array with similars keys/values into an array within that array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects, higher-order-functions

I currently have an array of objects and some of them have duplicate key values, specifically the country key in this example. I'm trying to join all the objects in that array with the same country value into an array within that objects array itself.

```
const objects = [
  { name: 'name1', url: 'name1.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name2', url: 'name2.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name3', url: 'name3.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name4', url: 'name4.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name5', url: 'name5.com', country: 'IT' },

  { name: 'name6', url: 'name6.com', country: 'CN' },
  { name: 'name7', url: 'name7.com', country: 'CN' },
  { name: 'name8', url: 'name8.com', country: 'CN' },

  { name: 'name9', url: 'name9.com', country: 'AL' },

  { name: 'name10', url: 'name10.com', country: 'CZ' },
  { name: 'name11', url: 'name11.com', country: 'CZ' },

  { name: 'name12', url: 'name12.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name13', url: 'name13.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name14', url: 'name14.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name15', url: 'name15.com', country: 'GB' },

  { name: 'name16', url: 'name16.com', country: 'TR' },
  { name: 'name17', url: 'name17.com', country: 'MN' },
];
```

So ideally i want the above array of objects to look like this, where the similar are grouped into an array inside that array, including objects that don't have repeated countries, i want them in their own array too:

```
const newArrayofArrayofObjects = [
  [
    { name: 'name1', url: 'name1.com', country: 'IT' },
    { name: 'name2', url: 'name2.com', country: 'IT' },
    { name: 'name3', url: 'name3.com', country: 'IT' },
    { name: 'name4', url: 'name4.com', country: 'IT' },
    { name: 'name5', url: 'name5.com', country: 'IT' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'name6', url: 'name6.com', country: 'CN' },
    { name: 'name7', url: 'name7.com', country: 'CN' },
    { name: 'name8', url: 'name8.com', country: 'CN' }
  ],
  [{ name: 'name9', url: 'name9.com', country: 'AL' }],
  [
    { name: 'name10', url: 'name10.com', country: 'CZ' },
    { name: 'name11', url: 'name11.com', country: 'CZ' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'name12', url: 'name12.com', country: 'GB' },
    { name: 'name13', url: 'name13.com', country: 'GB' },
    { name: 'name14', url: 'name14.com', country: 'GB' },
    { name: 'name15', url: 'name15.com', country: 'GB' }
  ],
  [{ name: 'name16', url: 'name16.com', country: 'TR' }],
  [{ name: 'name17', url: 'name17.com', country: 'MN' }]
];
```

I tried to achieve what i want with the following code:

```
let newObjects= [];

Object.entries(objects).forEach(([key, value]) => {

    for (let i=0; i < objects.length; i++){
        newObjects.push([{ name: value.name, url: value.url, country: value.country}])
    }

});
```

Not quite achieving what i want, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group the data by country using [Map object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```js
const objects = [
  { name: 'name1', url: 'name1.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name2', url: 'name2.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name3', url: 'name3.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name4', url: 'name4.com', country: 'IT' },
  { name: 'name5', url: 'name5.com', country: 'IT' },

  { name: 'name6', url: 'name6.com', country: 'CN' },
  { name: 'name7', url: 'name7.com', country: 'CN' },
  { name: 'name8', url: 'name8.com', country: 'CN' },

  { name: 'name9', url: 'name9.com', country: 'AL' },

  { name: 'name10', url: 'name10.com', country: 'CZ' },
  { name: 'name11', url: 'name11.com', country: 'CZ' },

  { name: 'name12', url: 'name12.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name13', url: 'name13.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name14', url: 'name14.com', country: 'GB' },
  { name: 'name15', url: 'name15.com', country: 'GB' },

  { name: 'name16', url: 'name16.com', country: 'TR' },
  { name: 'name17', url: 'name17.com', country: 'MN' },
];
const map = new Map();
objects.forEach((x) => {
  const key = x.country;
  if (map.has(key)) map.set(key, [...map.get(key), x]);
  else map.set(key, [x]);
});
const ret = [...map.values()];
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: Thanks @mr-hr 
You're a star! I really need to study the Map object as a whole as i thought map was only limited to array.map(item => item)

Answer (score 3):

You could group the objects with an object for same groups.

```js
const
    objects = [{ name: 'name1', url: 'name1.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name2', url: 'name2.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name3', url: 'name3.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name4', url: 'name4.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name5', url: 'name5.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name6', url: 'name6.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name7', url: 'name7.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name8', url: 'name8.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name9', url: 'name9.com', country: 'AL' }, { name: 'name10', url: 'name10.com', country: 'CZ' }, { name: 'name11', url: 'name11.com', country: 'CZ' }, { name: 'name12', url: 'name12.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name13', url: 'name13.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name14', url: 'name14.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name15', url: 'name15.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name16', url: 'name16.com', country: 'TR' }, { name: 'name17', url: 'name17.com', country: 'MN' }],
    grouped = Object.values(objects.reduce((r, o) => {
        (r[o.country] ??= []).push(o);
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

By having sorted data by `country`, or at least all same countries are grouped together, you could check the predecessor and create a new group.

```js
const
    objects = [{ name: 'name1', url: 'name1.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name2', url: 'name2.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name3', url: 'name3.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name4', url: 'name4.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name5', url: 'name5.com', country: 'IT' }, { name: 'name6', url: 'name6.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name7', url: 'name7.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name8', url: 'name8.com', country: 'CN' }, { name: 'name9', url: 'name9.com', country: 'AL' }, { name: 'name10', url: 'name10.com', country: 'CZ' }, { name: 'name11', url: 'name11.com', country: 'CZ' }, { name: 'name12', url: 'name12.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name13', url: 'name13.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name14', url: 'name14.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name15', url: 'name15.com', country: 'GB' }, { name: 'name16', url: 'name16.com', country: 'TR' }, { name: 'name17', url: 'name17.com', country: 'MN' }],
    grouped = objects.reduce((r, o, i, a) => {
        if (!i || a[i -1].country !== o.country) r.push([]);
        r[r.length - 1].push(o);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: upvoted for the brilliant use of the nullish coalescing operator - where did you get the `as-console-wrapper` from?

Comment: just write it in the CSS section. (somebody found it out, some years ago.)